# Textbox to label with two websites

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox, web, label

I have two sites in one of them i have a textbox and on the other site i have a label. What i want to do is have the value that is written in the textbox be passed on to the label in the next website on a button click.

Website1.aspx (with the textbox)

```
protected void btnSpara_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
```

The textbox:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="tbxKommentar" runat="server" OnTextChanged="tbxKommentar_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
```

Website2.aspx (with the label)

```
<asp:Label ID="lblKommentar" runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

How would i go about doing this.

Answer (score 0):

So what you are asking is how to pass value from one page to another. There are several options and all of them are described here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6c3yckfw.aspx

Code sample:

```
    protected void btnSpara_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         Response.Redirect("Website2.aspx?txt="+ tbxKommentar.Text);
    }
```

In your Website2.aspx:

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e){
    lblKommentar.Text = Request.Params["txt"];
}
```

Comment: What i'm trying to do is to pass on the text that you write on the textbox website1 to the label in website2. So basically just transfer the written text in website1 to website2.

The link didn't help me that much.

Comment: I will update my answer now with some code example. Hopefully it will help.